# jQuery/CSS - How do I find the quantity of specifically CSS-styled elements?

Tags: jquery, css, list, html-lists

I need to find the QUANTITY of all of the instances of ONLY the `<li style="display:none;">` UNDER ONLY the `<ul id="bob">`, as I will have other `<li>` pieces throughout document:

```
e.g.:

<ul>
  <li> a </li>
  <li> b </li>
  <li> c </li>
</ul>

<ul id="bob">
  <li style="display:none;"> 1 </li>
  <li style="display:none;"> 2 </li>
  <li style="display:none;"> 3 </li>
  <li style="display:inline-block;"> 4 </li>
  <li style="display:inline-block;"> 5 </li>
  <li style="display:inline-block;"> 6 </li>
</ul>
```

The amount of `<li>` are dynamically generated in my script, so it's not an obvious, visible number like '3' in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bob li[style*="display:none"]')
```

This will find all your li elements inside #bob, with a style attribute containing the word "display:none".

```
var elements = $('#bob li[style*="display:none"]');

elements.length;
```

This will give you the number of elements found.

You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2B7uv/5/) here.

Comment: You're welcome. Study both jQuery selectors and (more generally) regular expressions. You will get an increase in productivity and faster code.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) should work in this case.

```
alert( $("#bob li:hidden").length );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery size](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

$("#bob li").is(':hidden').size()

Comment: "The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; **however, the .length property is preferred** because it does not have the overhead of a function call."

Answer (score 0):

`$('#bob > li:hidden').length` should do.

Relevant links:

- [:hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)
- [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/):

> the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call